# Destructure array of objects with renaming

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I know this is a more than easy question and many similar ones exist here, but I couldn't find a quick solution.

So I just want to create a variable called `age2` that holds the value of `Mikes` age, so 29.

```
let arr = [
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 29
  },
  {
    "name": "Michael",
    "age": 24
  }
]
```

I thought this should work:

```
let [first: {age: age2}] = arr
```

To first get the first element and then destructure the object, but it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
```

Comment: `let [{ age: age2 }] = arr` would work, although I'm not sure this is more readable than creating "in-between" variables.

Comment: There's no such thing as `first`. In an array destructuring, the position will determine the element. So, just use `let [{age: age2}] = arr`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find method to get the 'Mike' object, then pull the age:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 29
  },
  {
    "name": "Michael",
    "age": 24
  }
]

let age2 = arr.find(function(element){return element.name == "Mike"}).age

console.log(age2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting elements of an array isn't part of destructuring syntax, it's part of basic Javascript syntax.

You could use array destructuring, but it gets unwieldy if you need more than one:

```
let [{age: age2}] = arr; //first element
let [{age: age2}, {age: age3}, {age: age4}] = arr; //more...
```

You could also specify the element you want to destructure:

```
const {age: age2} = arr[0];
```

Or you could remap the whole array to be in that format:

```
const people = arr.map(({name, age:age2}) => ({name, age2}));
```